# symfony2 add multiple selected languages to database through doctrine

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am using Symfony 2.5 and one of my entity has to save multiple languages saved against the entity while create/update.

I saw a list of languages available in Symfony core[Resources] and a [field type language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/language.html) also presents to generate a language field for form.

So, How do I map one-to-many relationship with the core list of languages from my Entity in Doctrine? I can't, because I don't have any existing entity to serve a list of languages to be added to `target-entity` in ORM mapping.

Or Do I have to create a separate custom language entity for the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to create annoter entity for that you can use "array" type to stock languages ids

```
/**
 * @Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 * @var array
 */
private $languages;
```

- array: Type that maps a SQL CLOB to a PHP object using serialize()
  and unserialize() - See more at:
  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html